# after running program leave interactive shell to use

Tags: bash, shell, exec, zsh

I want to run any program given as argument, through shell then
want that shell left as interactive shell to use later.

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -i <<EOF
$@
exec <> /dev/tty
EOF
```

But it is not working with zsh

```
#!/bin/bash
zsh -i <<EOF
$@
exec <> /dev/tty
EOF
```

as well as if somebody know more improved way to do it
please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach 1: bash, zsh and a few other shells read a file whose name is in the `ENV` environment variable after the usual rc files and before the interactive commands or the script to run. However bash only does this if invoked as sh, and zsh only does this if invoked as sh or ksh, which is rather limiting.

```
temp_rc=$(mktemp)
cat <<'EOF' >"$temp_rc"
mycommand --option
rm -- "$0"
EOF
ENV=$temp_rc sh
```

Approach 2: make the shell read a different rc file, which sources the usual rc file and contains a call to the program you want to run. For example, for bash:

```
temp_rc=$(mktemp)
cat <<'EOF' >"$temp_rc"
mycommand --option
if [ -e ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
rm -- "$0"
EOF
bash --rcfile "$temp_rc"
```

For zsh, the file has to be called `.zshrc`, you can only specify a different directory.

```
temp_dir=$(mktemp -d)
cat <<'EOF' >"$temp_dir/.zshrc"
mycommand --option
if [ -e ~/.zshrc ]; then . ~/.zshrc; fi
rm -- $0; rmdir ${0:h}
EOF
ZDOTDIR=$temp_dir zsh
```

Comment: Neither bash nor zsh on my system accept `--rcfile=...` option. Bash is 4.1.9(2), zsh is 4.3.11. Bash accepts only `--rcfile ...` (without `=`), zsh accepts `--rcs ...` (again without `=` and with different name). You don't have to name rcs file `.zshrc`: for me `zsh --rcs <(echo "echo abc")` worked well despite the fact that `<(...)` generates name like `/proc/self/fd/{N}`.

Comment: @ZyX: Now how did I manage to get both wrong? You're right about bash (it doesn't respect GNU conventions!). Zsh's `--rcs` only tells it to read the usual files, which it does by default (`--norcs` is the useful option); when you ran it, you just executed a script, without dropping into interactive mode afterwards.

Comment: Missed this fact. I somehow managed to get additional zsh in outputs of `pstree -h` with `--rcs` option and thus thought it is a replacement for `--rcfile`. Cannot reproduce this now, guess it is because I launched something like `zsh -h` in order to get help before (`zsh -h` sets `histignoredups`).

Comment: By the way, here is fourth approach: use `screen` and `screen -S launchedSession -X stuff $'mycommand --option\n'`.

Comment: Seems it is necessary to use `rm -- "$temp_rc"`
Also had to use `bash --init-file`, not `bash --rcfile`

Comment: @SindreMyren `rm -- "$temp_rc"` wouldn't work without also exporting the variable. Why not use `$0`? With bash, `--init-file` and `--rcfile` are synonymous.

Comment: @Giles:
For me `$0` would resolve to `bash`.
For Ubuntu 10.04 LTS at least `--rcfile`, even if mentioned in the man file, did not have the same effect as `--init-file`. Could be a bug that has been fixed the latest three years;-)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply start a new shell for interactive input?

```
#!/bin/sh
$@
exec zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in a script to call gui programs from the shell, haven't tested it with zsh though

```
nohup $@ >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Comment: That will work in zsh too, but an equivalent shortcut syntax would be `$@ &>/dev/null &!` to redirect both stdout and stderr and execute in the background with nohup.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ~/bin/ish
#!/bin/zsh
bash -i <<EOF
$@ < /dev/tty
exec <> /dev/tty
EOF

$
$
$ ~/bin/ish vim
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

At this point vim is opened.

```
$ vim < /dev/tty
$ exec <> /dev/tty
$ 
$
```

shell is left for you to do other work.
In my question the bash shell's STDIN was HEREDOC (<< EOF) so for
so it not working for command who want to read from TTY.
But after providing the command input from /dev/tty it start working.

I am not able to find how to correct warning

```
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```