# (Script)How to start gnu screen interactively and then run some command in it?

Tags: bash, exec, gnu-screen

What I want to achieve is as the following:

1. Start from bash in some terminal
2. Run gnu screen: `exec screen`
3. Start my desktop session in background: `startx &`
4. So now I end up with a terminal with screen running and X running in backgroud(in some vt) ready to use and connect from elsewhere through screen.

But I want to automate the above procedure in a script(in fact to put it in my ~/.bashrc). What's the simple and elegant way to do it?

The closest shot I got is like this:

```
exec screen bash -c "startx; bash"
```

but this way startx cannot get into background. That is,

```
exec screen bash -c "startx &; bash"
```

won't work.

Also, I ran into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218889/after-running-program-leave-interactive-shell-to-use) when googling. But

```
exec screen bash -i << EOF
startx &
exec < /dev/tty
EOF
```

don't work either. I also tried

```
exec screen bash -i --rcfile /tmp/somefile
```

with `startx &` in /tmp/somefile. Again not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: on another note, I don't think, you want to put `startx` in `~/.bashrc` :-)

Comment: @anishsane thanks for commenting. I would put startx into ~/.bashrc plus some logic to determine which tty it is, so startx will only run on a specific tty. I used to do that, now it's just adding a layer of screen makes things messy.

Comment: @BenJackson Would you please elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

Both `&` and `;` are command terminators; you can only use one or the other.

```
exec screen bash -c "startx & bash"
```

Comment: Wow! It kind of works. Thank you! However, in the above commandline the startx & process does not belong to the interactively running bash(running "jobs" there would show nothing), so it's a little bit different from manually starting. Is it possible to completely simulate the manual procedure?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. There's no way that I know of to start a `bash` shell with a script, then "drop" into an interactive shell (similar to `python -i`). You might be able to play with a screen command that simply stats a bash shell, then sends the key sequence "startx &<cr>" to simulate typing it, but I'm not familiar enough with `screen` anymore to suggest how to do that.

Comment: It turns out that my last commandline in the question will work if I exchange the -i option and the --rcfile option, because in bash all long options has to be placed before short options. Anyway I will accept your answer if no more answers today :-)